# ConstraintLayout: setMinimumHeight() vs setMinHeight()

Tags: android, user-interface, android-constraintlayout

I am using ConstraintLayout as the parent class for my customview and I want to set minimal height.
I've tried ConstraintLayout.setMinHeight(int value) and View.setMinimumHeight(int minHeight) and noticed that setMinimumHeight doesn't do anything and setMinHeight works perfect. What the difference between these methods? Aren't they same?

```
`@RemotableViewMethod
public void setMinimumHeight(int minHeight) {
    mMinHeight = minHeight;
    requestLayout();
}`

`public void setMinHeight(int value) {
    if (value == mMinHeight) {
        return;
    }
    mMinHeight = value;
    requestLayout();
}`
```

init-method of my custom view class:

```
 `init {
    layoutParams = LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    updateLayoutParams {
        // minimumHeight doesn't work here
        minHeight = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.min_height).roundToInt()
    }

    populateAttributes(attrs, defStyleAttr)
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've tried ConstraintLayout.setMinHeight(int value) and View.setMinimumHeight(int minHeight) and noticed that setMinimumHeight doesn't do anything and setMinHeight works perfect. What the difference between these methods? Aren't they same?

No. `ConstraintLayout` [defines it's own private member named](https://cs.android.com/androidx/constraintlayout/+/main:constraintlayout/constraintlayout/src/main/java/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout.java;drc=60381b8d6a073eecb241dab0b0b754f203a6c02b;l=561) `mMinHeight` which it uses internally in its layout calculations.

This is different from [the `mMinHeight` variable defined in the base `View` class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a175a5b/core/java/android/view/View.java#2465).

So `setMinimumHeight` updates the `View.mMinHeight` variable (which `ConstraintLayout` apparently does not use), while `setMinHeight` updates `ConstraintLayout.mMinHeight`, which it does use. Hence the difference in behavior you observe.